# Grouping Columns in MIBs for SNMP

Tags: snmp, mib

I have a table in SNMP like this:

```
Id    Name    A.x   A.y   B.x  B.y
1     Test     1     2     1    3
2     Next     3     4     5    6
```

I can make this accessible using SNMP as

```
table.1.1 = 1             table.1.2 = 2
table.2.1 = Name          table.2.2 = Next
table.3.1 = 1             table.3.2 = 3
table.4.1 = 2             table.4.2 = 4
table.5.1 = 1             table.5.2 = 5
table.6.1 = 3             table.6.2 = 6
```

So the assignment of columns would be

```
1 = Id   2 = Name   3 = A.x   4 = A.y   5 = B.x   6 = B.y
```

However for some reasons (such as being able to add A.z and B.z later on in the "right order"), I want to have the columns as follows:

```
1 = Id   2 = Name   3.1 = A.x   3.2 = A.y   4.1 = B.x   4.2 = B.y
```

My data would then look like this:

```
table.1.1 = 1             table.1.2 = 2
table.2.1 = Name          table.2.2 = Next
table.3.1.1 = 1           table.3.1.2 = 3
table.3.2.1 = 2           table.3.2.2 = 4
table.4.1.1 = 1           table.4.1.2 = 5
table.4.2.1 = 3           table.4.2.2 = 6
```

Basically SNMP (which only requires that all data can be iterated over with some start OID for every column and has no further internal rules for tables) allows that.

**However can it be expressed in MIBs?**

Are clients able to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want. But, if you want to obey the "Structure of Management Information" standard RFC 2578, then section 7.1.12 Conceptual
Tables at

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-7.1.12

explains the rules that you already know. Most apps will not know your ad-hoc table layout.

Comment: But I don't see how that contradicts my layout. Let's look at the example given there. `evalString` could very well be defined as `{ evalEntry 2 1 }` and `evalValue` as `{ evalEntry 2 2 }`. Why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The assignments you propose, where some of your columnar objects are not direct sub-nodes of the row but instead have an intermediate sub-node between them, are not legal. The relevant rules are defined in [RFC 2578 section 7.10(2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-7.10), Mapping of the OBJECT-TYPE value:

> (2)  If the object corresponds to a conceptual row, then at least one
> assignment, one for each column in the conceptual row, is present
> beneath that object.  **The administratively assigned name for each
> column is derived by appending a unique, positive sub-identifier to
> the administratively assigned name for the conceptual row.**

Emphasis mine. The meaning is clear: your columns' OIDs **must** be assigned by a **single** subidentifier appended to the row's OID (note that "name" means OBJECT IDENTIFIER value. The textual label one tends to think of as a name is called a "descriptor".)